# Change the font color and size of UISegment Control

Tags: iphone, uisegmentedcontrol

I want to change the font color and font size of uisegment control. is is possible ?

if any one has do this and any one has solution please tell me or share any helpful link

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As some other answers mention, you can also use [setTitleTextAttributes:forState:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html)

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12.0f];
NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:font
                                                       forKey:UITextAttributeFont];
[segmentedControl setTitleTextAttributes:attributes 
                                forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 2):

better use image for the same

```
- (void)insertSegmentWithImage:(UIImage *)image  atIndex:(NSUInteger)segment animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

Answer (score 2):

Check This

```
NSArray *ary=[sgmntControl subviews];
NSInteger intCount=0;
for (id seg in ary) 
for (id label in [seg subviews]) 
if ([label isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
{
    if(intCount==1)
    {
        [label setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]]; 
        [label setShadowColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    }
    else {
        [label setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [label setShadowColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    }
    [label setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16]];
    [label setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0,1)];

}
```

Thanks